# convert project from visual studio 2008 to 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008

i need some information

i have developed one windows appliaction in Visual studio  2008 with csharp.net with .net framework 3.5

Now i want to open the same in visual studio 2010 .
will this  project open in 2010.

Comment: Yes and no. VS will (try) convert it to a 2010 solution, and then open that. As @Graham say give it go, wouild have been quicker than asking the question wouldn't it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you don't have VS 2010 and you are sending it to someone with VS 2010 :)

Yes, it will open in Visual Studio 2010. While opening you might be asked to do some conversion so that project can be successfully opened in newer version of Visual Studio. Just click next/finish and Visual Studio will automatically do it for you

Answer (score 1):

Just open it. VS will do conversion automaticaly

Answer (score 0):

Do a fast backup of your current project/solution, zip everything and open with VS2010.
If something goes wrong you can revert to VS2008.

Comment: VS will create a backup of modified files for you. There is an option to enable/disable the Backup on the conversion dialog.

Answer (score 0):

If you start CS 2010 it will start to convert your Project and provide you information about the conversion process.

It will only modify the solution file (*.sln). And can create an optional backup of the old files. So you don't have to care about a manual backup of you whole project.

In my own project where we use VS2008 and 2010 I made a coppy of the old solution, called it *_2008.sln and then converted the original one to VS2010. You can manage the same projects and everything works fine. Just when you add or remove projects you have to update the solution file (in my case that do not happen).

Converting back from 2010 to 2008 might be more difficulty, so keep your Backup if you expect someone to work on the project with VS2008 in future.